# Message exchange between applications on different networks

Tags: network-programming, message

- we have 2 networks that cannot be connected (they belong to different organizations), but are physically located in the same building.
- we have a s/w utility that runs on one network and needs to receive messages and process them from another utility, running on another one.

What would be the easiest solution for this (without needing to connect networks)?

Answer (score 0):

In Java there exists the Java Messaging Service which provides a technology and tools to solve similar problems. But without connecting the networks it will be difficult. Maybe there exists a similar technology for your programming language.

Is it possible to have a machine in both networks and use it as message gateway? Route over the internet with a public reachable service in the receiving network? Special rule on the firewall to allow only this messages from network A to network B?

Just some ideas without knowing your real setting and requirements!